# Studying quantized algebras, why introduce $q^{1/2}$ instead of just $q$?

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups, q-analogs, quantum-calculus

In the fields of representation theory and [quantum algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290522/64073), we often study *quantized* versions of algebraic objects by regarding them as algebras over $\mathbf{C}(q)$, [or some subring of $\mathbf{C}(q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3403022/167197), and using that algebra structure to *twist* the multiplication. Now I often see the introduction of a different indeterminate $v$ such that $v^2=q$, and we work over $\mathbf{C}(v)$ instead. Furthermore, I usually see a different version of the $q$-analogue of $n$ being used in this context. Letting $n_q$ be the usual $q$-analogue of the integer $n$ as defined in [Quantum Calculus](https://www.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-0071-7) by Kac and Cheung, I often seen this different analogue $n_v$, where
$$
n_q \;=\; \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}
\qquad\qquad
n_v \;=\; q^{\frac{1-n}{2}}n_q \;=\; \frac{v^n-v^{-n}}{v-v^{-1}}
$$

What is the motivation of considering $v = q^\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $q$,
and considering this scaled $q$-analogue $n_v$?

Comment: I've favourited this question because I'd never realised the classical $q$-analog gains the nice property $n_{1/v}=n_v$ my answer notes with such a tiny tweak as $q=v^2$.

Comment: @J.G. This makes sense. In Kac and Cheung's book, using $n_q$ they emphasize the fact that you get two different $q$-analogues of the exponential function. I'll need to check but, since $n_v = n_{1/v}$, I think using $n_v$ instead makes these two exponential functions agree.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious motive for $n_v$ is its satisfying $n_{1/v}=n_v=\sqrt{n_qn_{1/q}}$. By contrast, $n_{1/q}=q^{1-n}\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$.